# Get client ip address in Angularjs / ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a php vote system where I check the voting table for the user ip address before inserting new votes into the vote table...

My question is how do I get the client ip address in my input form using angularjs.

I am building a mobile app with IONIC framework for android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd have to get it from your server-side (PHP) application. See [`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`](http://php.net/manual/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Am building a mobile app with IONIC framework for android... how is that possible?

Comment: Might have been a good idea to mention that earlier

Answer (score 8):

You can try like this

```
var json = 'http://ipv4.myexternalip.com/json';
$http.get(json).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result.data.ip)
}, function(e) {
    alert("error");
});
```

Or

If you don't wanna to use external service, you can use this cordova [plugin](https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface) [ working [example]](http://www.gajotres.net/retrieving-ip-adress-using-cordova-without-external-service/)

Like this

```
networkinterface.getIPAddress(function (ip) { 
    alert(ip); 
});
```

Comment: Just a comment... it should be result.data.ip

Comment: nope response is `{"ip":"x.x.x.x"}` ..so data will `result.ip` @JohnAndrews

Comment: Currently the answer contains `data`, so the answer will be: `console.log(result.data.ip);`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi your code working fine but when i put in my application then it's throw me 'Allow Access Origin Error ' if you have any idea then please tell me .